# How to get cross point from perpendicular line (B->A) and (middleBC->C)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, trigonometry

How can I draw a curve which is part of the circle (depending on the end point)?

Let:

- `A=(Ax,Ay)`
- `B=(Bx,By)`
- `C=(Cx,Cy)`
- `BC(BCx, BC.y)` are middle point between `B` and `C`
- `A` and `B` are `L1`
- `B` and `C` are `L2`

How do I get the point `cross(Mx,My)` from the perpendicular line `(B->A)` and `(middleBC->C)`?

Any ideas how to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: These are basic geometry concepts. If you don't know these you should probably try to learn these before trying to code it. Anyway you can use geometry libraries do them for you.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume line `l1` is the line perpendicular to `AB` from point `B`. You have one point from this line (`B`) and you have its slope (Because its perpendicular to `AB`). So you can simply write its equation.

And assume line `l2` is the line perpendicular to `BC` from point `middle BC`. again you can write `l2` equation similar to what explained above.

The desired point is intersection of `l1` and `l2`. So you simply have to solve the system of equations of `l1` and `l2`.

Answer (score 2):

Let `I((B.x + C.x) / 2, (B.y + C.y) / 2)` be the middle point of `[BC]` and `I'(I.x + I.y - C.y, I.y + C.x - I.x)` (90° rotation of `C` around `I`). Then the perpendicular to `(BC)` going through `I` is `I + tII'` (for any real number `t`). Likewise with `B'` be the 90° rotation of `A` around `B`, the perpendicular to `(AB)` going through `B` is `B + uBB'` (for any real number `u`).

[image]

Now you just have to find the intersection point of these two lines. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/1126268) for related issues.

Comment: @Brieg: This is a description (a kind of parametrized equation, actually) of the line. It is just use for the purpose of mathematical notation, you don't have to code it really. In fact, you should rather check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line) (the link in my answer is rather for line _segments_ intersections). So, given two points on each line (B and B'/I and I') you can compute the coordinates of M.

Comment: @Brieg: I can't reach your link.